# Common ways to use a Qt shared library with an application and cmake

Tags: c++, qt4, cmake, shared-libraries

At the moment I have an application and a (static) library, both written in Qt. As build system I use cmake. I link the library with `target_link_libraries` to the executable and everything works fine (and I have one file/executable).

But now I want to use a shared library. Creating a shared library with `add_library` and the keyword `SHARED` works, but I am a bit confused about the way, how to load a shared library. I saw two "ways":

1. Write a library and use `Q_DECL_EXPORT` / `Q_DECL_IMPORT`. They load the library with `QLibrary` and use a typecast to resolve all (C) functions
2. Write a library and include the header file in the application. The shared library is "passed" to the executable with the cmake command `target_link_libraries`. They don't use QLibrary to load the library.

Now I have a few questions:

1. What is the common ("normal") way to load a shared library ? Export all C++ methods to C functions with __cdecl (Way 1) or include the header file (Way 2)? Other solutions?
2. Related to way 2 (Include header) - how is the library loaded ? By the operating system ? If I move the library, the application cannot find the library -> Library loaded at runtime ?
3. Is there a way to load a library without including a header or use it at compile time (Load library at runtime)? I read there is a way, but it isn't that easy

I hope that my questions are clear and not "noobish", otherwise please write a comment

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess the second way is more common, though I met both.
2. In second way library is loaded by os on application startup. If os cannot find library - the application won't start.
3. No matter which method you are using, you need to know functions' semantic. This means you will include header, which contains them, this way or another.

Also Qt gives you another way to load a library in runtime, using plugin method: [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/plugins-howto.html#the-lower-level-api-extending-qt-applications)